# Masking an RGB image with Binary mask Code in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, masking, image-masking

I have a RgB image (MxNx3) and binary mask which is a image consisting of 0's and 1's.
Anywhere that the mask is 0, I wish to make exactly 0 in the original image, while anywhere the mask is 1 I just want to leave alone.
Any solutions on how to proceed to achieve  the desired results?

Comment: Element-wise multiplication or/and matrix indexing is/are your friend/s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be your solution,

```
mat_new=mat_rgb.*mat_binary
```

`. (dot)` before a operator will make element wise operation on the matrices.

Comment: This will work with newer versions of MATLAB. For older versions, you'll need to use `bsxfun` to match the MxNx3 image and MxN mask image.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I would like add a bit to the question. How could I know how much pixels are removed while performing the masking?

Comment: the total number of masked pixel should be `MxN - sum(mat_binary((:,:))`
Because number of masking = number of zeros , which i calculated.